# requirejs - jquery and pager is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, requirejs, pager

I am a newbie for requirejs, I am trying to include jquery, knockoutjs and pager. When I use the following code,

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js',
    paths: {
        app: 'viewModels'
    }
});

requirejs(['lib/jquery', 'lib/knockout', 'lib/pager'], function($, ko, pager){
    console.log($, ko, pager);
});
```

It consoles,

```
undefined 
Object {b: function, r: function, version: "2.3.0", a: Object, utils: Object…}
undefined
```

Then, I have changed the code to,

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js',
    paths: {
        app: 'viewModels',
        jquery: 'lib/jquery',
        pager: 'lib/pager'
    }
});

requirejs(['jquery', 'lib/knockout', 'pager'], function($, ko, pager){
    console.log($, ko, pager);
});
```

It consoles,

```
GET http://localhost/aravind/ui-arc/js/knockout.js 404 (Not Found) require.js:34
Uncaught Error: Script error for: knockout
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

Again I changed the code to,

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js',
    paths: {
        app: 'viewModels',
        jquery: 'lib/jquery',
        knockout: 'lib/knockout',
        pager: 'lib/pager'
    }
});

requirejs(['jquery', 'knockout', 'pager'], function($, ko, pager){
    console.log($, ko, pager);
});
```

Everything is working fine. Can someone explain what is the problem here?

Comment: Your last example is the correct one. I don't know why was ko working in your first example, maybe you had kncokout referenced somewhere globally... but still the last one is it correct `requriejs.config`